# Wordpress edit custom jquery don't works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to add jquery custom functions to my edit post page on Wordpress. To make this i load jquery-1.4.2.min.js. Now functions works fine, but collapse buttons doesn't works.

Here it's my code.

On plugin file php

```
function gestion_edit_enqueue_scripts( $hook ) {

    if( !in_array( $hook, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) ) )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'JQuery', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'gestion_edit',                         // Handle
        plugins_url( '/js/gestion_edit.js', __FILE__ ),  // Path to file
        array( 'JQuery' )                             // Dependancies
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'gestion_edit_enqueue_scripts', 2000 );
```

And on .js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).ready(function() {
        });

        jQuery('#title').live('change', function(event) {
            value = $('#title').val().toUpperCase();
            $('#title').val(value);
            });
});
```

In this example i want all post uppercase, but i need other functions.

How can i do to make my js works, and wordpress collapse too.

Thanks

Comment: Are all the js files included properly? Looking at the docs, you don't need that leading slash in the `plugins_url` call BTW

Comment: Js are loaded fine. But when it's loaded, wordpress postbox collapse button doesn't works. I think that it's for jquery conflict, but i don't know sure

Comment: what errors are thrown? Can't use `$` without passing it as argument to ready callback due to likelihood of `noConflict()` use in theme. Why using such old jQuery version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not include the new jQuery just change the code to use `on` instead of `live`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery(document).on('change', '#title', function(event) {
                    var value = jQuery('#title').val().toUpperCase();
                    jQuery('#title').val(value);
                });
            });
```

Comment: Why you are using `live` when you can do this with `on` with current version of wordpress jquery ?

Comment: I have multiple errors, but i don't know if it affects it. Here copy/paste https://justpaste.it/kn6f

Comment: I would suggest you use the wordpress default jQuery and change your function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75750/discussion-between-javiercabot-and-sumit).